# Replace IP Address from file

Tags: bash, sed, replace, ip, hostname

Sample.txt file:

```
.........................
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system ip is not found
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP is 172.16.80.10
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP:172.16.80.10
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
Hostname::ip-172.16.80.10.ec2.internal
some log file entries
some log file entries
......................
```

I want to replace the IP Address from file not the host name, however it is changing hostname also.

I am using this command to replace IP address:

```
sed s/172.16.80.10/172.16.80.12/g  sample.txt
```

Getting Output

```
.........................
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system ip is not found
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP is 172.16.80.12
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP:172.16.80.12
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
Hostname::ip-172.16.80.12.ec2.internal
some log file entries
some log file entries
......................
```

(Changing Hostname also)

Desired output is

```
.........................
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system ip is not found
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP is 172.16.80.12
some log file entries
some log file entries
This system IP:172.16.80.12
some log file entries
some log file entries
some log file entries
Hostname::ip-172.16.80.10.ec2.internal
some log file entries
some log file entries
......................
```

Code example:

```
while getopts i:h: opt
  do
  case $opt in
  i)
    CurrentLocalIpv4=`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4`
    if [[ $OPTARG =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      sed -i s/"$CurrentLocalIpv4"/"$OPTARG"/g /home/ec2-user/sample.txt
      echo "ip cahnged"
    else
      echo "fail"
    fi
    ;;
    h)
      echo"hostname"  ;;
   esac
 done
```

Comment: can you format you input? it's unreadable

Comment: see [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and also add the output you get from the command you used as well as expected output...

Comment: i made changes in this post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your command, you can modify it as follows:

```
sed 's/172.16.80.10$/172.16.80.12/g' sample.txt
```

That is, telling `sed` that you want only change the lines with the IP to be changed and which have no more characters after it (172.16.80.10$).

In case of you have the IP to be modified within a variable, ($CurrentLocalIpv4), you may write it as follows:

```
    sed 's/'$CurrentLocalIpv4'$/172.16.80.12/g' sample.txt
```

Comment: yeah its working but if i use verable instead of putting ip directly how do i write this command

Comment: sed 's/'$CurrentLocalIpv4'$/'$OPTARG'/g' sample.txt

Comment: +1, this should work fine for IP addresses, due to their format. In the general case that the variable can have spaces, asterisks `*`, etc, you should double quote the variable like this: sed `'s/'"$CurrentLocalIpv4"'$/172.16.80.12/g' sample.txt`, but it is still fragile, as it will fail if there are any forward slashes (`/`) in the variable. Also any regular expression meta-characters (like the dot `.`) may cause unexpected/unwanted behaviour if not escaped first.

Comment: if i want to use for all other files how can i do ...i am matching ip address in the file   sed -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/172.31.18.12/g' sample.txt